# Why does this reaction go from yellow to green to red in color?

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy

In this youtube video by chemicalforce:
https://youtu.be/3cvUXW__QZ0

When he heats the lithium metal to metal fire point we see a yellow flame. When he brings the SF6 close it becomes green and when he touches it to the metal it sizzles red.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Seems like this questions should be asked on [chemistry.se].

Comment: For context, the reaction of interest is $8\mbox{Li}+\mbox{SF}_6\to\mbox{Li}_2\mbox{S}+6\mbox{LiF}$. Lithium fluoride is yellow-white; lithium's flame test colour, presumably showing due to the heat allowing $4\mbox{Li}+\mbox{O}_2\to2\mbox{Li}_2\mbox{O}$, is red. I'm hoping a chemist can explain the green.

Comment: The well-known crimson flame lithium flame test color is lithium atomic emission around 670.78 nm. The green is likely from sulfur or sulfur-containing flame species: there was air present in the demo. The yellow I assume is just from the bulk lithium burning.

Comment: @EdV I have seen boron burning green characteristically

Comment: @ChemEng Sure, and barium and copper salts and some phosphorus compounds, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiophosphoryl_fluoride , and likely quite a few other things. But, as a chemist who did spectroscopy, I really prefer seeing spectra obtained with spectrometers! ;-)